# Theorem about equivalence relations.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Is this theorem true ?

Theorem: Assume R is a relation on a set A.The relation R partitions the elements of A into classes if and only if R is an equivalence relation.

My counter example is:

Let A = {1,2} and R = {(1,2),(2,1)}
The class generated by 1 is {2} and the class generated by 2 is {1}.
And {1} and {2} completely partition A but R is not reflexive.

Comment: Presumably the context surrounding the Theorem says something to the effect that the classes defined by a relation consist of elements which are all related to each other (and that the elements in two different classes are not related).  In your example, there would be no classes.

Comment: What does "The relation R partitions the elements of A into classes" means?  You can talk about classes only if there is already an equivalence relation.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_on_Equivalence_Relations

Comment: Your relation is not reflexive.

Comment: Here is the definition of a class in my book: "If R is a relation on A and a∈A define the class generated by a to be the set {b∈A: a R b}"

Comment: You have misunderstood. An equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Your relation is only symmetric.

Comment: @JohnDouma That's the point of the OP, the relations is not a equivalence relation.

Comment: @JohnDouma   As stated, the theorem asks you to prove that a relation is an equivalence relation (given the partition).  The OP's has proposed a counterexample.

Comment: Ok, that's an unusual definition of "class". But with that definition of class the relation does generate a partition of $A$, so your counterexample is correct.

Comment: @gokalpgokalp  If nothing else, that ought to be called a right-class (or a left-class, depending on conventions) as you might get different classes if you used $\{b\in A:\,bRa\}$, for instance.  But if that's really the definition they want, then your counterexample is valid.

Comment: @jjagmath The equivalence relation generated by the partition $\{1,2\}$ contains $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: I'll just use another resource.I think that author doesn't mean the "class" that i understood.Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDouma First: $\{1,2\}$ is not a partition. That would be $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Second. The OP is working with a general relation (not necessarily an equivalence relation) and giving its definition of class generated by that relation.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Proofs by Jay Cummings

Comment: I don't have that text at hand. If I did, I would want to check the exact wording of the definition and theorem. Based on what you wrote, I agree with lulu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem. Your definition of a class is the set of all things equivalent to a given element. Your class generates the partition $\{1\}, \{2\}$

Note that your relation, although it generates the class, is not an equivalence relation. The equivalence relation for your partition is $a$ is equivalent to $b$ if and only if $a=b$.

The theorem states that a partition is the same as an equivalence relation. It does not say that if any relation generates a partition then that relation is an equivalence relation. In fact there are two separate theorems:

1. If $R$ is an equivalence relation on a non-empty set $A$ then the set of equivalence classes forms a partition of $A$.
2. Given a partition $P=\{A_1,\dots, A_n\}$ then the relation induced by the partition, $x$ is equivalent to $y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same $A_i$, is an equivalence relation.

Therefore, the theorem that you wrote is incorrect.

Comment: See [this](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_220_Discrete_Math/6%3A_Relations/6.3%3A_Equivalence_Relations_and_Partitions) for more information.